# Mongoose Upsert, Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

I have experiencing a problem upserting with Mongoose. It says Syntax is invalid, says `unexpected token "."` at last line. But I cannot understand what is really wrong. I have been looking into it for more than one hour, am I missing a simple concept?

```
var seriesSchema = new Schema({
    type : {type: Number, default: 1},
    features: {
        tvdb_id: {type: Number, unique: true},
        ....
    },
    created : {type: Date}
});

var SeriesModel = mongoose.model('Series', seriesSchema);

var instance = new SeriesModel();                   
// Setting instance properties to some values
SeriesModel.update({features.tvdb_id : serieData.id}, instance, {upsert: true});
```

Comment: is `serieData` a typo for `seriesData` ?

Comment: @ColinPickard yes, it shoulb be series data but it gives error at features.tvdb_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use dot-notation as a JSON key unless you quote the key, like this:

```
SeriesModel.update({"features.tvdb_id" : serieData.id}, instance, {upsert: true});
```